# Laravel custom user specific functions

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

What and how would be the best method to create custom functions to use in views? I'm quite new to Laravel and I couldn't understand even after a lot of searching.

This is how I currently check if a user is an admin in my view for example:

```
@if (Auth::user()->group === "admin")
    <p>You're an admin</p>
@endif
```

What would I have to do, to make this a function, so I could do something like this instead?

```
@if (Auth::user()->isAdmin)
    <p>You're an admin</p>
@endif
```

Comment: you better use 2nd option because it is based on `roles`. And you find it useful in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `User` model, add the following method:

```
public function inGroup($name)
{
     return $this->group == $name;
}
```

Now in your templates, you can do:

```
@if(Auth::user()->inGroup('admin'))
    <!-- User is in the 'admin' group -->
@endif
```

Note how naturally that reads: *If the user is in the group named 'admin'*.

As your application scales, you can keep this single method instead of having to define multiple methods to check the user's group (isAdmin, isSubscriber, isPremium, etc).

Comment: This is a very good idea, better than separate functions for group checks. Thanks!

Comment: You forgot to add a closing bracket to the view check ")" @Amo :)

Answer (score 1):

Since `Auth::user()` returns an instance of the `User` model, you can simply add a method on there:

```
// this is in the User class
public function isAdmin()
{
    return $this->group == "admin";
}
```

And then call it like so:

```
@if (Auth::user()->isAdmin())
    <p>You're an admin</p>
@endif
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. I tried doing dumb stuff, like writing an extra class or calling a function from my controller. Didn't even know you could add a function to the user class like this smh.

Comment: By making the function name getIsAdminAttribute() you can call it without the brackets, as if it was stored in the database.